# Pages are not loaded

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Ionic router outlet is used bit it does not work.

```html
<ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
```

The standart Angular router works.

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

[Ionic router](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router-outlet) provides only integration with the framework. But at the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ion-router-outlet-bug) it is shown that it provides tabs functionality.
Is it for tabs only?
Should I use the router-outlet as the main paging approach for ionic?

Comment: what is the version of the ionic you are using? Can you check your package.json and let us know?

Answer (score 0):

**first:** In order to be able to bring the site up, you must first set `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

**Second:** After that, you have to define the routing in the AppRoutingModule as an example below
`const routes: Routes = [ {path: '' , component: RegisterComponent}, ];`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest ionic version, `<ion-router-outlet>` should be used without the `main` attribute as mentioned below.

```html
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```